# Subsetting a corpus based on content of textfile

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I'm using R and the tm package to do some text analysis. 
I'm trying to build a subset of a corpus based on whether a certain expression is found within the content of the individual text files.

I create a corpus with 20 textfiles (thank you lukeA for this example):

```
reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")
corp <- VCorpus(DirSource(reut21578), list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))
```

I now would like to select only those textfiles that contain the string "price reduction" to create a subset-corpus.

Inspecting the first textfile of the document, I know that there is at least one textfile containing that string:

```
writeLines(as.character(corp[1]))
```

How would I best go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `tm_filter`:

```
library(tm)
reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")
corp <- VCorpus(DirSource(reut21578), list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))

( corp_sub <- tm_filter(corp, function(x) any(grep("price reduction", content(x), fixed=TRUE))) )
# <<VCorpus>>
# Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
# Content:  documents: 1

cat(content(corp_sub[[1]]))
# Diamond Shamrock Corp said that
# effective today it had cut its contract prices for crude oil by
# 1.50 dlrs a barrel.
#     The reduction brings its posted price for West Texas
# Intermediate to 16.00 dlrs a barrel, the copany said.
#     "The price reduction today was made in the light of falling   # <=====
# oil product prices and a weak crude oil market," a company
# spokeswoman said.
#     Diamond is the latest in a line of U.S. oil companies that
# have cut its contract, or posted, prices over the last two days
# citing weak oil markets.
#  Reuter
```

How did I get there? By looking into the [packages' vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf), searching for *subset*, and then looking at the examples for `tm_filter` (help: `?tm_filter`), which is mentioned there. It might also be worth looking at `?grep` to inspect the options for pattern matching.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler way using the **quanteda** package, and one more consistent with the way that reuses existing methods already defined for other R objects.  **quanteda** has a `subset` method for corpus objects that works just like the subset method for a `data.frame`, but selects on logical vectors including document variables defined in the corpus.  Below, I have extracted the texts from the corpus using the `texts()` method for corpus objects, and used that in a `grep()` to search for your pair of words.

```
require(tm)
data(crude)

require(quanteda)
# corpus constructor recognises tm Corpus objects 
(qcorpus <- corpus(crude))
## Corpus consisting of 20 documents.
# use subset method
(qcorpussub <- corpus_subset(qcorpus, grepl("price\\s+reduction", texts(qcorpus))))
## Corpus consisting of 1 document.

# see the context
## kwic(qcorpus, "price reduction")
##                       contextPre         keyword             contextPost
## [127, 45:46] copany said." The [ price reduction ] today was made in the
```

Note: I spaced your regex with "\s+" since you could have some variation of spaces, tabs, or newlines instead of just a single space.

Comment: I'm a bit confused that the out of this is a large character vector, I was expecting a smaller corpus. Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: Found it: use 'corpus_subset' instead of 'subet'

Answer (score 0):

@lukeA's solution works. I want to give another solution I prefer.

```
    library(tm)

        reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")
        corp <- VCorpus(DirSource(reut21578), list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))

        corpTF <- lapply(corp, function(x) any(grep("price reduction", content(x), fixed=TRUE)))

        for(i in 1:length(corp)) 
          corp[[i]]$meta["mySubset"] <- corpTF[i]

        idx <- meta(corp, tag ="mySubset") == 'TRUE'
        filtered <- corp[idx]

        cat(content(filtered[[1]]))
```

Advantage of this solution by using meta tags, we can see all corpus elements with a selection tag *mySubset*, value *'TRUE'* for our selected ones, and value *'FALSE'* for otherwise.

Comment: Many thanks for this addition. I agree, it is very useful!